# How do I replace first space with comma in UNIX

Tags: unix

My Question is, I have 2 columns. The text in the secound column has comma seperated values. I want the 2 columns to be deisplayed as comma seperated and the comma seperated text in 2nd column should remain as it is.

E.g: A,B being the name of the columns:

```
A   B
123 Hi There
234 Hello there
```

I want the output as

```
A,B
123,Hi There
234,Hellothere
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use  this `sed` command

```
sed -r 's/\s+/,/' File_Name
```

or

```
sed -r 's/ +/,/' File_Name


 -r, --regexp-extended

          use extended regular expressions in the script.
```

**Output :**

```
A,B
123,Hi There
234,Hello there
```

Comment: note the output does not match with the desired by the OP. Maybe you want to use `sed 's/ \+/,/'` instead, so that multiple spaces between columns will be also replaced.

Comment: @fedorqui ,**Thank you**. Your suggestion has improved my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try, `sed 's/ /,/' filename.txt`.

Comment: Mind this only works for the first space or whatever char you choose to search.

Comment: This works better on the bash from osx10...which doesn't support the '-r' regex. If you search as global. it replaces ALL spaces...but without global it only replaces the first found space of each line.