# Insert comma before a specific word in .txt in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have text file and it has content like this,

```
40 number of cpu
50 number of errors
```

and I need to insert comma between number and words. Its should be like this,

```
 40, number of cpu
 50, number of errors
```

Comment: You want to replace the first space with a comma followed by a space? In this case I recommend you to have a look at `sed` and its search and replace function.

Comment: *Which* commands did you try? You are expected to show some efforts, specifically as the sort of problem has been asked and answered *many* times before.

Comment: This might help with `sed`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35238699/3776858

Comment: `awk '{ print $1 ",", $2, $3, $4 }'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put comma after the first word in a line:

```
sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+/&,/' file.txt
```

Put comma after the first word in a line, only if it's numeric:

```
sed -E 's/(^[[:space:]]*[0-9]+)([[:space:]]|$)/\1,\2/' file.txt
```

Put comma after every numeric field:

```
sed -E 's/(^|[[:space:]])([[:digit:]]+)($|[[:space:]])/\1\2,\3/g' file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working in my code. Is there any resourses to learn about regex in sed ?

Comment: @NavinduWIjeratna The POSIX specification for [sed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and for [regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) are a good reference. I also like this reference for [POSIX character classes](https://github.com/micromatch/posix-character-classes).

Comment: @NavinduWIjeratna In the answer I used "extended regular expressions" (`-E`); character classes: `[[:space:]]` is all white space characters, `[^[:space:]]` is _not_ whitespace characters; `+` is "one or more of", `*` is "zero or more of"; back references: `\1` refers to the first parenthesised (`( )`) expression, `\2` to the second, etc.; `&` is replaced with the whole match.